# React:styled-components modal alert success icon

Tags: modal-dialog, styles, react-typescript

I am using react-typescript in my app. For styling I am using [style-components](https://styled-components.com/). I am creating one Modal alert component. My modal alert is ready and it looks like this, [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN4dh.png). I am checking this [sweet alert site](https://sweetalert2.github.io/). In there they have success icon. I want to use it in my Modal alert component. But I don't know where to find this icon and how to use it in my modal alert component.

**This is my modal alert component**

```
import React from 'react';
import iconX from './close.svg';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Modals = styled.div`
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
`
const ModalOverlay = styled.div`
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
cursor: pointer;
`

const ModalBox = styled.div`
position: relative;
width: 80%;
margin: 0 10%;
padding: 50px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: white;
cursor: auto;`

const ModalTitle = styled.div`
color: #9E25FC;
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
`

const ModalContent = styled.div`
margin-top: 30px;
color: #6B6B6B;
font-size: 16px;`

const ModalClose = styled.button`
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
right: 20px;
transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
&:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
`
interface IModalProps {
  title: string;
  isOpen: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  children?: JSX.Element | string[] | string;
  icon?: JSX.Element; //This is icon i am declaring. I am not sure is it JSX.Element.
}

export default ({ title, isOpen, onClose, children }: IModalProps) => {
  const outsideRef = React.useRef(null);
  const handleCloseOnOverlay = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    if (e.target === outsideRef.current) {
      onClose();
    }
  }
  return isOpen ? (
    <Modals>
      <ModalOverlay
        ref={outsideRef}
        onClick={handleCloseOnOverlay}
      />
      <ModalBox>
        <ModalClose
          onClick={onClose}
        >
          <img src={iconX} alt={'close'} />
        </ModalClose >
        <ModalTitle>
// I want to use it in here the success icon.
          {title}
        </ModalTitle>
        <ModalContent>
          {children}
        </ModalContent>
      </ModalBox>
    </Modals>
  ) : null;
};
```

Comment: So the question is are you using the `sweet alert site` library? Or you want to display the icon as it is displayed on that library?

Comment: I am not using sweet alert library. I am checking what kind of props I can use it to make my own alert. i want to display the icon as it is displayed on that library.

Comment: If you want to make it dynamic, you might need to add what kind of notification its is. So type will be your first prop and then apply switch case and render the icon conditionally.

Comment: Did you find the icon?

Comment: I mean the success icon

Comment: https://icons8.com/icons/set/list you'll find icons here